# Accordion list in mvc4

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-4

how to make the following list in accordion

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
 <div class="content">
   <div class="title">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.con_title)</div>
   <div class="frame">
   <div class="photo" >
   <img src="@Url.Content("Images/Contributeimage/"+ @item.con_image)" />
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="discription"><p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.con_notes)</p></div>
```

}

please help me

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`jQuery UI accordion`](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) plugin. The documentation is a good start. It contains many examples you may walk through.

Comment: it is worked...

but i want like that.. if one list is open another list is not closed.. what is the method for that

Comment: That's not what an accordion is. In an accordion when you expand some part, another part gets collapsed.

Comment: can you please tell me the solution for that